# I am trying to get the average length of all strings from a mixed array. But before I count, I want to only focus on the one part of this task

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement

Well, so far I have done:

1. I have assigned two variables - one is a mixed array and the other one is empty, so I can push the strings from the first one to the second.
2. I used the loop `for`, so the program can check every element of an array.
3. I have set the conditional statement: if the type of a specific element is a string, then it will be pushed to this empty array;
4. But if it's anything else, then it will be pushed back to the original array.
5. Display new array filled with strings from the first array at the chosen ID.
6. Call the function.
   But then the 'RangeError: invalid array length' pops up. I have no idea what went wrong and even how to fix that. Any ideas?

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Task number five</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Average length of the string in this array:</h2>
  <p id="averageLength"></p>
  <br>
  <h2>The sum of all the numbers in this array:</h2>
  <p id="sumNumbers"></p>
  <script>
    const firstArray = ["String 1", { name: "Lola" }, 2, 32.22024, false, 2.1112, true, "String 2", "String 3", "Jim likes dogs", [], {}]
    const stringArray = [];
    function countAverageString(data) {
      for ( let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        if (typeof data[i] === "") {
          stringArray.push(data[i]);
        }
        else {
          firstArray.push(data[i]);
        }}
        return firstArray;
        return stringArray;
        document.getElementById("sumNumbers").innerHTML = stringArray;
       }
    countAverageString(firstArray);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

At first, I did not have the 'return' at the end of the conditional statement, hence I though that it was missing. But it was not and still is not the issue, since it has nothing to do with the length, so at this point I do not even know what's wrong.

Comment: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) never returns  `''`.

Comment: FYI, you are not using HTML `H2` elements correctly. The first heading element on a page should be an `H1`. Then, if you want to create sub-sections of the page, the next heading would be an `h2` and if you needed to sub-divide the `h2`, you'd then use an `h3` and so on. Headings should not be chosen based on the way the browser styles the text, they are to define the document structure and assist those who rely on screen readers.

Comment: Also, `br` elements are meant to break up a block level element, so they shouldn't be outside of `p` elements and really shouldn't be used for adding extra vertical space to the overall document layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues here. First, you don't have to push current object back to original array. When you read it, it stays there. Second, once you return from a function, rest of the function is not executed.

Have a look into [typeof documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for how to use it. I would also suggest to have a look into [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of array.

Your updated `countAverageString` method:

```
// rest of your code
    function countAverageString(data) {
      for ( let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        if (typeof data[i] === "string") {
          stringArray.push(data[i]);
        }
      }
      document.getElementById("sumNumbers").innerHTML = stringArray;
    }
    countAverageString(firstArray);
```

Or you can do:

```
const stringArray = firstArray.filter(i => typeof i === "string");
```